# save table sort in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to be able to refresh the page and have my table still sorted as a left it. And I'd like to do this with local storage and not a jQuery plugin.

The table sorts, but I don't understand why the localStorage doesn't save the order that it was last left.

What am I doing wrong with localStorage?

I have my sort table function that calls the saveLocalStorage() function after each sort.

```
function sort_book_table(tbody, col, asc) {
     ... sorts ...
     saveLocalStorage();
}

function saveLocalStorage(){
      var table_layout = $('#bookTable')[0].innerHTML;
      localStorage.setItem(table_layout);
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance

edit: added quick fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1k901cdr/

Comment: Please make sure you have a minimal repro of your situation in the question. For one, how are you "sorting" things. And how are you reloading / getting the item? Etc.

Comment: @Jeroen Apolgies. I'll post a quick fiddle in just a sec.

Comment: look in browser console for errors! Should be telling you you can't set data that way

Comment: @Jeroen added fiddle

Comment: @Modelesq, check my answer for all operation of localStorage with reference url that will help you to understand overall

Comment: @Venkatraman Hey dude! I'll test it out! Thank you for posting! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The localStorage object provides a Storage object for an origin.

You missed second parameter in `localStorage.setItem(table_layout);`. Try the below snippet for all your operation on `localStorage`.

```
// Setting the Value.
localStorage.setItem("keyName", "value"); // Syntax
localStorage.setItem("table_layout", table_layout); // by variable
localStorage.setItem("table_layout", "dsdssd"); // by value

// Get the value.
localStorage.getItem("table_layout");

// Clear one item.
localStorage.removeItem("table_layout");

// Clear all items.
localStorage.clear();
```

Reference:
https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage.setItem` Needs a key and a value.

```
localStorage.setItem('foo'); // incorrect
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar'); // correct
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the key value.

```
localStorage.setItem('layout', table_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Micah's answer, setItem takes two arguments, a key, and a value.

`localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar'); // correct`

However, it also appears that you are attempting to save the entire HTML of the table in localStorage. You should only be saving the sort column and direction. Here are updated functions that would persist the column and direction of the sort.

```
function sort_book_table(tbody, col, dir) {
    ... sorts ...
    saveLocalStorage(col, dir);
}

function saveLocalStorage(col, dir){
    localStorage.setItem('sortCol', col);
    localStorage.setItem('sortDir', dir);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to want to save the state after reload. Should I not call saveLocalStorage within the sort_book_table function?

Comment: After reload, before rendering the table, you'll need to retrieve the saved sort column and direction from local storage and use those values to sort the table correctly on first render.